# Update Your Amazon RDS SSL/TLS Certificates - do I need to do anything on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have an EC2 instance, and two separate databases - one Sql Server instance and one MySql instance - both within AWS RDS.

So when Amazon refers to client applications needing new certificates - does it only mean if I am connecting to those databases on AWS via clients on my PC (eg. Sql Server Management Studio, MySql Connector)?

Do I have to do anything to my asp.net and php web applications running on EC2, which connect to the AWS RDS instances?

Thanks for any clarification.

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The EC2 instances are clients of the database. If you are currently performing SSL Certificate validation on the EC2 instances when connecting to the RDS instances, then you need to update the certificates. If you are not currently performing SSL Certificate validation, then you don't need to do anything, except maybe go ahead and update your RDS instances with the new certificates so Amazon stops emailing and calling you about it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to update anything in code as ssl handshake is managed by the driver.

Comment: If SSL certificate validation is enabled, not just SSL connections, but actual validation of the certificate, then the file would need to be updated on the EC2 server. That might require changing the DB connection string to point to the new file. It's not correct to just state that "the driver will handle it".